# when I reopen it it doesn't store the value of Label5 and TextBox1. In TextBox1 i want to show, after reopen, the zero value

Tags: vb.net

I have the following situation in Visual Basic. 5 Label, 4 TextBox and 2 Button according to the picture. TextBox1 + Textbox2 + TextBox3 = TextBox4 and Label4 = TextBox4. Button1 represents TOTAL at (TextBox1 + Textbox2 + TextBox3). Button2, represents SAVE. I want Label5 to show me, after pressing the SAVE Button, the value in TextBox1 and to be saved. This is the code used. Apparently the application works but when I reopen it it doesn't store the value of Label5 and TextBox1.  In TextBox1 i want to show, after reopen, the zero value . Please help me!

THIs IS THE CODE

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim t1 As Integer
        Dim t2 As Integer
        Dim t3 As Integer
        Dim t4 As Integer
        Dim total1 As Integer

        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, t1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, t2) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, t3) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, t4) Then

            total1 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Introduceti 1 sau 0. Ati introdus o litera")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TextBox4.Text = total1.ToString

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click


        Label5.Text = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.QQQ = Label5.Text
        My.Settings.QQQ = TextBox1.Text
        My.Settings.Save()




        Label4.Text = TextBox4.Text
        My.Settings.QQQ = Label4.Text
        My.Settings.QQQ = TextBox4.Text
        My.Settings.Save()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        TextBox1.Text = My.Settings.QQQ
        Label5.Text = My.Settings.QQQ





        TextBox4.Text = My.Settings.QQQ
        Label4.Text = My.Settings.QQQ


        If TextBox4.Text = " " Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.TextChanged









        If TextBox4.Text = " " Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

        If TextBox1.Text = " " Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If



    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Your mistake is so obvious, u save all value into my. Setting. QQQQ. It means the previous saved value of textbox1 is overwritten by textbox 4 value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm a beginner and I don't know much about this.  Please if you can tell me more details.  Thank you for yours time !

Comment: TextBox1=Label5 and TextBox4 = Label4

Comment: It is either you save the data into database, or some external file like XML and etc. If you save it to program setting, it will not be preserved. You will lost the info when the program is close. So tell me how do you want to save the data?

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work. Do you have any idea how I could upload a picture in which to explain better? –  f

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that your setting QQQ is scoped to User not Application so it can be updated. The Type should be String.

In Button2.Click you set the label and text box to display the same thing. Then you set the setting to equal the label text. Next you overwrite the setting with the text box value. This doesn't make sense. They are the same value.

Then you overwrite it 2 more times. Only the last assignment to settings, `My.Settings.QQQ = TextBox4.Text` will be preserved at the end of the method.

As a side note, in the TextChanged events, do you really mean a space character?  `" "` I think you may want and empty string `""`.

Just get rid of TextBox4 completely and use Label4 to hold the total. You don't want the user to be able change the total directly.

What is Label5 doing? Looks like that is unnecessary.

The User Settings are persisted between  sessions. When you set up a user setting in the project properties, it is stored in the app.config found in your project folder.

```
<userSettings>
    <TestCode3.My.MySettings>           
        <setting name="QQQ" serializeAs="String">
            <value />
        </setting>
    </TestCode3.My.MySettings>
</userSettings>
```

The actual Value is saved to user.config

C:\Users{username}\AppData{ApplicationName}\ continue to drill down until you reach user.config
[image]

This is just background information. You do not interact directly with these files.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = "0"
    Label4.Text = My.Settings.QQQ
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t1, t2, t3, t4 As Integer
    Dim total1 As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, t1) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox2.Text, t2) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox3.Text, t3) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(TextBox4.Text, t4) Then
        total1 = t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Introduceti 1 sau 0. Ati introdus o litera")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Label4.Text = total1.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    My.Settings.QQQ = Label4.Text
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

I think your main problem is overwriting the single setting you created.

Comment: Thank you.  But it does not work.  Do you have any idea how I could upload a picture in which to explain better?

Comment: @foXinTHEboX67 What doesn't work? Works for me.

Comment: https://web.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100015164145811

Comment: This is a photo with the app. THANKS for yours time!